# How to read random data for each request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have 4 input parameters which I need to pass in my http request sampler. Everything is OK but the problem is how to first data i have to pass from the previous thread http response and rest 3 from the csv file. Please help.

[image: Image attached]

Comment: I need to handle like that If my LOAN ACCOUNT NO is this then Service request number will read from previous request and rest will read from csv file OR first run of http request' service request number will read from previous request and rest from csv.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand, please edit and reframe

Comment: I have one input csv file in which I have four rows with multiple columns in each row. All these input parameters will run on one http request except first row as you can see in attachment that one column value will read from previous response output and from 2nd iteration onwards, data will read from csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to update a specific value of the CSV during execution. It would be wise to say that this can be achieved using if controller and User Parameters element. You can go through the below screenshots to resolve this problem.

**CSV Data set config for reading csv values**

[image]

**CSV File**

Here, I have added text "REPLACE_WITH_RESPONSE" so that we can match it in IF controller.

[image]

**IF CONTROLLER**

This will check if you want to replace this value or not.

[image]

**Users Parameters**

This element would be used to update the csv value with previous request response. In the below example, Date is the CSV value which is replaced with previous Response.

[image]

Hope the above solution will help you in resolving this problem.

Comment: Hi, I am facing two problems:                                                                                   
1) When I use the User Parameters then it doesn't read the value of a variable but when I use User Defined Variable then it reads the variable.                                                                     2) It runs only for first row then it skips rest rows. Please help

Comment: Make sure to use User parameters element in the same way I have used. The user parameters should work as per my screenshots. It would be great if you could provide here some screenshots of your implementation.

Comment: I am able to resolve it. I changed the MatchNo(0 for random) in JSON extractor to 1 and followed ur suggestions and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help you. :)